# Geckofx VB.net Obtain the url from Hyperlink vb.net

Tags: tabs, geckofx

I use Geckofx and I Want to know, How can I obtain the url from a hyperlink in geckowebbrowser.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Take the link like below

```
GeckoLinkElement link = new GeckoLinkElement(_myBrowser.Document.getElementById('your_link_id').DomObject);

link.click();
```

You need GeckoFX 21 and xulrunner 21 too